# Css property align-items: center in Flexbox losing height of columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now and I haven't managed to and a solution, despite the numerous similar questions.

From my understanding, the Flexbox system should calculate the height of the children elements automatically by simply adding `display: flex` to the parent element, as below:

```css
.list {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #edf2f6;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.list-search {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.list-search-input {
  flex: 4;
}

.list-search-button {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #354052;
  color: #edf2f6;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-search">
    <input class="list-search-input" placeholder="search" >
    <span class="list-search-button">Go</span>
  </div>
  
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 50px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <p>
     content yada yada yada
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, you'll see the text within the button is not centered vertically centered. So, to correct this, and as stated by numerous answers on SO, we'd add `align-items: center;` to the parent. However, when this is added, both of the columns lose their height:

```css
.list {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #edf2f6;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.list-search {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-search-input {
  flex: 4;
}

.list-search-button {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #354052;
  color: #edf2f6;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="list-search">
    <input class="list-search-input" placeholder="search">
    <span class="list-search-button">Go</span>
  </div>
  
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 50px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <p>
     content yada yada yada
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong in the css? How can I achieve both columns with 100% height of the parent, and vertically aligned text inside the button?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zxpa10s6/

Comment: @Michael_B Perfect. Can you add it as an answer then I'll accept to close the question off.

Comment: It's more appropriate for me to mark this question as a duplicate, since an answer already exists.